# ERROR in Invalid or unexpected token on Angular production build

Tags: angular, angular-cli

```
chunk {0} runtime.06daa30a2963fa413676.js, runtime.06daa30a2963fa413676.js.map (runtime) 1.5 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} main.9868d9b237c3a48c54da.js, main.9868d9b237c3a48c54da.js.map (main) 182 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} polyfills.85f47f0bf59079cbc23a.js, polyfills.85f47f0bf59079cbc23a.js.map (polyfills) 189 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} styles.da6a8dc1b4027cfd731e.css, styles.da6a8dc1b4027cfd731e.css.map (styles) 338 kB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in Invalid or unexpected token
```

I'm receiving the above error message on

```
ng build --prod
```

On other machines, the build works. Also, the debug build (ng serve) works as well. The error message provides no clue on where to start searching. What is the cause for this error and/or how can it be identified?

Here is some verion information:

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 6.8.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.6.8
@angular-devkit/core         0.6.8
@angular-devkit/schematics   0.6.8
@schematics/angular          0.6.8
@schematics/update           0.6.8
rxjs                         6.2.1
typescript                   2.7.2
```

Comment: try running it with --verbose=true

Comment: Since this seems a problem with your local machine, have you tried to re-clone the code into a fresh directory and then try again?

Comment: @JamieRees yes, with no success

Comment: you can also try to compare node.js versions. You seem to be running some old versions, angular included

Comment: thanks @PierreDuc, the node version it was!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved updating to the current version of node.js.

Answer (score 0):

Checks your angular.json file. It might be difference between  production and debug configurations.