# Syntax Error in Angular App in Certain Builds Only

Tags: angular, jenkins, angular-cli

I am modifying an existing Angular App, and have been for several weeks. I recently made some changes which work on my local version. I have a Jenkins job that builds a production version of the project and deploys the production files to a server, using this command:

`ng build --prod --base-href /projectname/ --output-hashing=none`

However, the files that get generated have a syntax error, which is visible when I try to view the site from the server

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oW5gC.png)

I've made sure all the src files are exactly the same and get the same error. I've also tried all the solutions suggested [here](https://dev.to/redslug/7-solutions-to-ejsonparse-or-unexpected-token-npm-install-error-20nh), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45222464/syntax-error-in-angular-app-unexpected-token/52694038), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55022061/error-in-invalid-or-unexpected-token-on-angular-production-build), but all seem to result in a different syntax error in the same `main-es2015.js` file.

Interestingly, when I run the same build command on my local, and copy the files from `dist` directly over to the server, the site works again. On both my local and Jenkins servers, I've removed node_modules and reinstalled, and since the src files are the same, I'm not sure where the discrepancy comes from, or how to prevent it in the future.

Comment: Been there, really frustrating. What kind of install command are you running in the build pipeline? If you're not already running ```npm ci```, I would do that instead of ```npm install```. ```ci``` is intended for continuous integration pipelines and 100% reinstalls every dependency. That's basically the same as deleting the node_modules first, but I'd at least run that once before running both locally and on the server.

Comment: my build pipeline is the following:
```npm cache clean -force;
rm -rf node_modules;
npm install;
npm update
```
I'll try npm ci and report back

Comment: Just checked: using ```npm ci``` in the above pipline did not fix the issue. I tried the same command on local, and that version worked again.

Comment: Do you have any bundler/minifier running separate from the Angular CLI in the build pipeline?

Comment: Very late reply. But back in September I ended up creating a new Jenkins project from scratch that performs the same function, and I have not encountered this error anymore.