# An unhandled exception occurred: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: angular

I keep getting the following error after i run `ng serve`:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Invalid or unexpected token
See "\mypc_path\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-Aij37E\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

This is what's inside `angular-errors.log`:

```
[error] \myproject_path\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\selectors\combinator.js:1
��I=]8����"q�y-L@�]��~U�w@"��^ٮw'��b�


SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Attuali\wherescrypto\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\parser.js:26:42)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
```

I tried many things suggested online like:

- Switching from yarn to npm (and back);
- Deleting my current `node_modules` folder and running again `npm i` and `yarn` (not together, one by one);
- Tried updating Node.js, NPM and Yarn;

I made an angular project from scratch, there are few libraries. The ones I installed are `ngx-bootstrap-icons` and `@angular/fire`

Any suggestion that can help?

### Edit

Forgot to mention that I also tried to uninstall ngx-bootstrap-icons library. I still get the same error.

### Edit 2

I was digging around the issue and I noticed this inside `node_modules/postcss-selector-parser/dist/selectors/combinator.js`:

```
��I=]8����"q�y-L@�]��~U�w@"��^ٮw'��b�
X�bz��=��| ��g�.��;{�
�g��Y�E"{9%�U�)���� "$3WD�I��LwK4��};�����F�v��.e�������
w
��Zg�vX$n]��    �c��_��n�?W�����SA�y�HdM�ä@�II��o d3_�n��f��u��&�����$�*v�{�6����}{WȽr/��N1Ë�*Rb�:��&�J�kx��ծ�T�R�ԶX�Β����,��j{��
�2���䆕�H�����S��>)W4��c�:�r�ez���f�W�~��Թ�2u�4!8=��h�s�V�M�$���ܹ�^����m��r#����v&�I
I?�n�%�BE����/0�������l�E�e���#���yE�����
a�Ի�a�)�y�Lޑ5Q��ʏ�|m���\HX#'_*�\��tFV=�C�U�I�qxZ�+v��$��x�!�\���������0lY�b2n�e�%#������"?t"�V��K^a#ׂ���
�3�,E�x ��+���P;fm,�*g1*V�x�vN��a��"M�(ϝ5s����fe1�G���\�c*&�]�j���]�"�!d���íP
```

That's too weird for me guys.

Comment: does update nodejs version solve the problem?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55022061/error-in-invalid-or-unexpected-token-on-angular-production-build

Comment: @AlexYu unfortunately as I said no, updating nodejs doesn't solve the issue. I already have node v.16.13.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved the issue, but it's not completely "clean".

After I saw that combinator.js was corrupted, I found the [repository folder](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-selector-parser/blob/master/src/selectors/combinator.js) of the official library.

I copied the code and pasted it by converting the import and exports, and now my `combinator.js` is like this:

```
const Node = require('./node');
const { COMBINATOR } = require('./types');

class Combinator extends Node {
    constructor (opts) {
        super(opts);
        this.type = COMBINATOR;
    }
}

exports["default"] = Combinator;
module.exports = exports.default;
```

Now, when I do `ng serve`, it compiles it correctly. Still, that files is not supposed to be corrupted in the origin. That's weird.

Answer (score 2):

The old "delete node_modules and re-run npm i" trick worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

go to your "project_folder"
delete "node_modules_folder"
run cmd and cd to the "project_folder"

at this point you can run "npm istall"
or
drag a working "node_modules_folder" from somewhere to your "project_folder"

after the install finish it should work!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33059446)

Comment: Would like to add to this answer. Be sure to have the correct node version before npm installing. Ya deleting the node_modules and re-installing them also solved my issue.